# CPU-usage or CPU-cycles of a process/pid with respect to the maximum CPU frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment I monitor several processes via Python's `psutil` modul and retrieve the CPU usage in percent, which is based on `execution_time/total_time`. Problem with doing it this way is the Dynamic Voltage and Frequency Scaling (DVFS, or ACPI's P-state, or cpufreq, etc.). The lower the current CPU frequency is, the longer a process needs to execute, the higher the CPU usage is. In contrast to this, I need the *fixed* CPU usage relative to the maximum performance of the CPU.

To avoid multiple rescalings with the permanently changing "current frequency", one approach was to use directly the CPU-cycles used by the process. In principal this can be done via `perf_event.h` in C or `perf` on a Linux command line. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a module for Python which provides similar functionality (based on the aforementioned ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to BlackJack's comment

> What about implementing it in C as shared library and using it via `ctypes` in Python?
>
> A library call introduces less overhead. A subprocess call starts a whole external process and communicates the result as string over pipes every time you need the value. The shared library is loaded *once* into the current process and the result is passed in memory.

I implemented it as a shared library. The source code of the library **cpucycles.c** is (heavily based on the example of [`perf_event_open`'s man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html)):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                    group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

long long
cpu_cycles(unsigned int microseconds,
            pid_t pid,
            int cpu,
            int exclude_user,
            int exclude_kernel,
            int exclude_hv,
            int exclude_idle)
{
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    long long count;
    int fd;

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_user = exclude_user;
    pe.exclude_kernel = exclude_kernel;
    pe.exclude_hv = exclude_hv;
    pe.exclude_idle = exclude_idle;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, pid, cpu, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
    usleep(microseconds);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    close(fd);
    return count;
}
```

This code is compiled into a shared library via the following two commands:

```bash
$ gcc -c -fPIC cpucycles.c -o cpucycles.o
$ gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libcpucycles.so.1 -o libcpucycles.so.1.0.1 cpucycles.o
```

Finally, the library can be used by Python in **cpucycles.py**:

```python
import ctypes
import os

cdll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libcpucycles.so.1.0.1"))
cdll.cpu_cycles.argtypes = (ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int,
                            ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int,
                            ctypes.c_int)
cdll.cpu_cycles.restype = ctypes.c_longlong

def cpu_cycles(duration=1.0, pid=0, cpu=-1,
                exclude_user=False, exclude_kernel=False,
                exclude_hv=True, exclude_idle=True):
    """
    See man page of perf_event_open for all the parameters.

    :param duration: duration of counting cpu_cycles [seconds]
    :type duration: float
    :returns: cpu-cycle count of pid
    :rtype: int
    """
    count = cdll.cpu_cycles(int(duration*1000000), pid, cpu,
                            exclude_user, exclude_kernel,
                            exclude_hv, exclude_idle)
    if count < 0:
                raise OSError("cpu_cycles(pid={}, duration={}) from {} exited with code {}.".format(
                    pid, duration, cdll._name, count))

    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it via `perf` command line tool reading the CPU-cycles and wrapped into Python (simplified code):

```
import subprocess
maximum_cpu_frequency = 3e9
cpu_percent = []
while True:    # some stop criteria
    try:
        cpu_percent.append(int(
                subprocess.check_output(["perf", "stat", "-e", "cycles",
                        "-p", pid, "-x", ",", "sleep", "1"],
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode().split(",")[0]
                )/maximum_cpu_frequency)
    except ValueError:
        cpu_percent.append(0.0)
```

Unfortunately, this is not exact due to the inexact `sleep` command as well as efficient due to spawning a new `perf` process for every sample.

Comment: What about implementing it in C as shared library and using it via `ctypes` in Python?

Comment: Does a library call introduce less overhead than a process call does? If so, this could probably be a more efficient approach. Unfortunately, it needs much more implementation in C which I am not really familiar with.

Comment: A library call introduces less overhead. A subprocess call starts a whole external process and communicates the result as string over pipes every time you need the value. The shared library is loaded _once_ into the current process and the result is passed in memory.

Comment: @BlackJack, can you copy/sketch your approach of using a minimal library in a separate answer, please? Even without any code I would like accept rather this idea as answer.